# Amber loading with script errors

Tags: smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

I was taking a look at amber, and was following the procedure as given here https://github.com/amber-smalltalk/amber/wiki/Getting-started. But when i run amber using bin\amber serve , i get a blank page and it has some unloaded scripts , which says

```
GET http://localhost:4000/bower_components/require-css/css.js 404 (Not Found)
```

and similar ones.

I am following the procedure as it is and why am i getting these errors. Also if i open the index.html file in browser , everything works fine. Anyone else faced theis before?

TIA

Comment: I would suggest you starting here: http://docs.amber-lang.net I had troubles with wiki too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @uko mentioned in his comment you should use the 'Getting Started' from http://docs.amber-lang.net/.
I just updated the wiki page to redirect users there.